# div that stays on top of status bar

Tags: html, css, statusbar

the div on website below that have search at the bottom and it always remain sticked above status bar if u scroll down.

**http://www.outlawdesignblog.com/**

can u kindly point me to a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a self-contained example of how they do that, tested in IE7 and FF3:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><style>
#staticpanel {
    background:#B85503 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-top:1px solid #C3702C;
    bottom:0;
    padding:12px 0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
</style></head><body>
<div id='staticpanel'>Hello!</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right IE doesnt support position:fixed. The easiest way to emulate position:fixed is too use dynamic expressions and have the expression calculate and update the absolute y position etc.

RichieHindle's example will however work for the other browsers.

Comment: I tested my example in IE7 and it worked perfectly.  IE6 might be a different story.